# Correct way of interpolating a value to a log message

Tags: python, logging

Is there some best practice for interpolating values into a log message? My google-fu is not effective here, but I get examples like [this](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/17358) which say:

```
#Change all logging from this

logger.warning("This is a %s" % var)

#to

logger.warning("This is a %s", var)
```

like its a best practice everybody must follow. Is there a reason? Will any values of `var` (like an object of a class) fail here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the latter. The logging module will only interpolate the value *when the message is processed*.

This mean you save CPU cycles for debug messages, for example, if the log level excludes them.

This is documented in the [`logging` HOWTO, "Optimization" chapter](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#optimization):

> Formatting of message arguments is deferred until it cannot be avoided.

You may want to follow the rest of the advice given in that chapter to avoid expensive calculations just for logging, as well.

Internally, the `logging` module uses the first form, so any value that cannot be converted to a string will fail.

Answer (score 1):

I think second form is better, because logger has a chance to check whether `warning` level is enabled before doing substitution.